# Is there a way to password protect the certifcate files in the KeyValStore in HFC?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

The Hyperledger Fabric Client provides a way to create a KeyValStore using the following command:

```
hfc.newFileKeyValStore
```

However, the certificate files created inside (e.g., member.admin) are text files that are not password protected (i.e., through encryption).  This means that if a computer is shared by more than one user there is a possibility that the certificate file can be stolen.

Is there a command in HFC which creates certificate files that are password protected/encrypted?

Outside of HFC, I can encrypt the certificate files and decrypt them before a HFC client uses it.  I can just delete the decrypted version once the HFC client is closed.  However, there is a risk that the decrypted version will not be deleted (e.g., computer shutdown improperly).

Answer (score 1):

*hfc.newFileKeyValStore* seems to be v0.6 specific. In Hyperledger Fabric 1.0, you can implement api.KeyValueStore interface. Here is the comment from the api.js in https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/master/fabric-client/lib/api.js

"The SDK provides a default implementation based on files. An alternative
implementation can be specified using the "KEY_VALUE_STORE" environment
variable pointing to a full path to the require() package for the module."

You can write your own implementation that does create password protected or encrypted files.